# Change text color of existing text

Tags: c#, richtextbox, textcolor

I've written an application that has a richtextbox in it with a black background. Therefore I have to write in it using white text. That all works fine by setting the fore color to white. If I however copy text from Word that is black into my textbox, that text remains black.

I need to change the color of that text. So this is what i've tried so far: (the textbox is named txtMessage)

```
txtMessage.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

That doesn't have any effect on the existing black text though.

Then I tried this:

```
private void txtMessage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s = txtMessage.SelectionStart;
        txtMessage.SelectAll();
        txtMessage.SelectionColor = Color.White;
        txtMessage.Select(s, 0);

    }
```

It in principle works fine but of course every time I edit the text in the textbox (not copying something in there, but simply typing) the whole thing is executed with every letter I type resulting in a flickering ( I guess because all is selected and then deselected every single time).

So does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this elegantly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you targeting? Just tested on VS2010 targeting .NEt 4.0 Client Profile and copy/paste black text from Word stay white in the RichTextBox control even with black background and white color specified.

Comment: The newest one I guess. I'm using VS2012 and my laptop is pretty new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are typing in the box an the colour is set to white, there is no need to run the code.

You only need to run it when you add text that you haven't typed (eg copy/paste from your example).

Therefore, use that code in the TextChanged event, but perform a check before running it as to whether the user has typed the text or added it another way

EDIT: Check the answer to this question: [Detecting a paste into a RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636532/detecting-a-paste-into-a-richtextbox), it might help you

Comment: Thank you,I also had that idea. Though I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. That seems very reasonable and easy.

Comment: So I as I'm using a richtextbox, there is this property undoactionname which turns out to be very useful as it takes on the value "Paste" if text was pasted.

Comment: Does it also show if the user, eg, drag-dropped data into the box?